# Testing on an older iOS version with a real device

Tags: iphone, ios, downgrade

I have a feature that uses the camera so I can test it only on a device, I need to test it on older than iOS 4.3.5, However all of my iPhones are already at 4.3.5. 
Is there a way to downgrade the iOS so i could test it on older iOS?

Comment: If you have saved your SHSHs, you can downgrade your iOS version using tinyUmbrella (but I think that you may have to jailbreak)

Comment: I didn't save the SHSH, anyway i think that 4.3.5 doesn't have jailbreak yet

Comment: It is quite lame that Apple doesn't give us a means to downgrade a device to aid in testing.  The simulator can only test so much as my app uses the camera and other features not supported by the Simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to do a downgrade to the iPhone OS to an older version unless the phone is jailbroken.

Answer (score 0):

If your device was ever jailbroken, try looking into recovery of SHSH blobs to downgrade your iOS version. Otherwise, I don't know a way to achieve this.

Comment: my device was never jail broken.